# Define a function createSquareMat_sumpos(...) which receives one argument, dim, an integer number greater than

Tags: python-2.7

Define a  function createSquareMat_sumpos(...) which receives one argument, dim, an integer number greater than 0, and it returns a list of lists which represents a matrix of dimension  dim x dim, so that each element in the matrix has as content the sum of the column + the row position.

As an example, the following code fragment:
print (createSquareMat_sumpos(2))

should produce the output:
[[0, 1], [1, 2]]

Comment: Stackoverflow is no code writing service. Show what you've tried and where you are facing problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def createSquareMat_sumpos(dim):
        list=[[]]*dim
        for i in range(len(list)):
            list[i]=[i,(i+1)] #### not sure what to write here ####
        return list
```

this works for

print (createSquareMat_sumpos(2)) and gives [[0, 1], [1, 2]]

but print (createSquareMat_sumpos(3)) I need it to give me [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

instead of

[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]]